# When displaying or viewing files in website whether it can downloaded automatically

Tags: c#, html

when viewing a PDF or png/jpeg files in website, is there any chance to it can be
downloaded automatically to my computer. If yes then where it would be stored please tell me i searched more in Google but, it helpless to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding an extra `download`  attribute in your link, like this

```
<a href="/images/example.jpg" download>
```

on clicking of this hyperlink file is downloaded automatically. This attribute is only used if the href attribute is set.

The value of the attribute will be the name of the downloaded file. There are no restrictions on allowed values, and the browser will automatically detect the correct file extension and add it to the file (.img, .pdf, .txt, .html, etc.).

If the value is omitted, the original filename is used. (Plese note that it is not supported in IE and Safari.)
The download attribute is new for the  tag in HTML5. like,

```
<a download="filename">
```

Comment: Thanks i need some more details i need to only view files in my web project user could not download or print the file using ctrl+s , right click the file to save it in local and print please tell how to achieve this